# SSIS precedence constraint - expression with AND

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server SSIS.

In a precedence constraint, how do I use an `AND` within the expression?

For example if I have:

```
@myVariable1 == 0 AND @myVariable2 == 0
```

I get the message

> Expression cannot be evaluated

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I know the double pipe operator is a logical `OR`, is there something similar for `AND`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `&&` like so

```
@myVariable1 == 0 && @myVariable2 == 0
```

here is complete list of SSIS expression operators:

| Operator | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Cast | Converts an expression from one data type to a different data type. |
| () (Parentheses) | Identifies the evaluation order of expressions. |
| + (Add) (SSIS) | Adds two numeric expressions. |
| + (Concatenate) | Concatenates two expressions. |
| - (Subtract) | Subtracts the second numeric expression from the first one. |
| - (Negate) | Negates a numeric expression. |
| * (Multiply) | Multiplies two numeric expressions. |
| / (Divide) | Divides the first numeric expression by the second one. |
| % (Modulo) | Provides the integer remainder after dividing the first numeric expression by the second one. |
| || (Logical OR) | Performs a logical OR operation. |
| && (Logical AND) | Performs a logical AND operation. |
| ! (Logical NOT) | Negates a Boolean operand. |
| | (Bitwise Inclusive OR) | Performs a bitwise OR operation of two integer values. |
| ^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR) | Performs a bitwise exclusive OR operation of two integer values. |
| & (Bitwise AND) | Performs a bitwise AND operation of two integer values. |
| ~ (Bitwise NOT) | Performs a bitwise negation of an integer. |
| == (Equal) | Performs a comparison to determine if two expressions are equal. |
| != (Unequal) | Performs a comparison to determine if two expressions are not equal. |
| > (Greater Than) | Performs a comparison to determine if the first expression is greater than the second one. |
| < (Less Than) | Performs a comparison to determine if the first expression is less than the second one. |
| >= (Greater Than or Equal To) | Performs a comparison to determine if the first expression is greater than or equal to the second one. |
| <= (Less Than or Equal To) | Performs a comparison to determine if the first expression is less than or equal to the second one. |
| ? : (Conditional) | Returns one of two expressions based on the evaluation of a Boolean expression. |